# Token generation for Einstein Sentiment API

Tags: api, oauth, einstein, security-token

I am trying to implement the sentiment api but having issue while generating the access token.

I have uploaded einstein_platform.pem file in Files in Salesforce.

```
ContentVersion con = [SELECT  Title
                ,VersionData
        FROM    ContentVersion
        WHERE   Title = 'einstein_platform'
        OR      Title = 'predictive_services'
        ORDER BY Title
        LIMIT 1];

    String key = con.VersionData.tostring();
    key = key.replace( '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '' );
    key = key.replace( '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '' );
    key = key.replace( '\n', '' );
    JWT jwt = new JWT( 'RS256' );
    jwt.pkcs8 = key;
    jwt.iss = 'developer.force.com';
    jwt.sub = 'demo@gmail.com'; // Update with your own email ID
    jwt.aud = 'https://api.einstein.ai/v2/oauth2/token';
    jwt.exp = String.valueOf(3600);
    String access_token = JWTBearerFlow.getAccessToken( 'https://api.einstein.ai/v2/oauth2/token', jwt );
    String keyaccess = access_token;
    System.debug('******keyaccess**'+keyaccess);
```

Output:
18:34:11:987 USER_DEBUG [21]|DEBUG|******keyaccess**null

Comment: Try taking a look at the [JWTBearerTokenExchange Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange). Otherwise your issue may be that you need to create a connected app since you appear to be using a private key.

Comment: Might hep you [Einstein Token](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2017/10/02/salesforce-einstein-vision-quick-overview/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to storing the **einstein_platform.pem** file you also need to update the following line with the email address you used when creating the Einstein account.

```
jwt.sub = 'demo@gmail.com';
```

Also, check that you have **https://api.einstein.ai** configured as a Remote Site so the callout will be allowed.

Comment: Yes, I did update my email id, here I just put it for demo purpose only.